# Git diff: ignore lines starting with a word

Tags: regex, git, git-diff

As I have learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53450186/git-diff-show-only-changes-not-matching-a-pattern), we can tell `git diff` to ignore lines starting with a `*` using:

```
git diff -G '^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]*]'
```

How do I tell git to ignore lines starting with a word, or more (for example: `* Generated at`), not just a character?

This file shall be ignored, it contains only trivial changes:

```
- * Generated at 2018-11-21
+ * Generated at 2018-11-23
```

This file shall NOT be ignored, it contains NOT only trivial changes:

```
- * Generated at 2018-11-21
+ * Generated at 2018-11-23
+ * This line is important! Although it starts with a *
```

Comment: Probably a dupe of [ignoring changes matching a string in git diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878622/ignoring-changes-matching-a-string-in-git-diff)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git is using [POSIX](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) regular expressions which seem not to support [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html). That is the reason why [@Myys 3's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53452408/2020827) does not work. A not so elegant workaround could be something like this:

```
git diff -G '^\s*([^\s*]|\*\s*[^\sG]|\*\sG[^e]|\*\sGe[^n]|\*\sGen[^e]|\*\sGene[^r]|\*\sGener[^a]|\*\sGenera[^t]|\*\sGenerat[^e]|\*\sGenerate[^d]).*'
```

This will filter out all changes starting with "`* Generated`".

Test: https://regex101.com/r/kdv4V0/3

Answer (score 3):

Considering you are ignoring changes that does **NOT** match your regex, you just have to put the words you want inside the expression within a lookahead capture group, like this:

```
git diff -G '^(?=.*Generated at)[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]*]'
```

Note that if you want to keep adding words to ignore, just keep adding these groups (don't forget the `.*`):
However, if the string contains a "Generated at" **anywhere** in their whole, it shall be ignored. If you want to define exactly how it should start, then replace the `.` with a `[^[:word:]]`.

```
git diff -G '^(?=[^[:word:]]*Generated at)[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]*]'
```

You can have a look at it's behaviour at

**Version 1:** `.*`

https://regex101.com/r/kdv4V0/1

**Version 2:** `[^[:word:]]*`

https://regex101.com/r/kdv4V0/2

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, git version 2.7.4 seems not to support this regex, I am getting `fatal: invalid regex: Invalid preceding regular expression`.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: git diff -G is not able to exclude changes only to include changes that match the regex.

Have a look at [git diff: ignore deletion or insertion of certain regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328577/git-diff-ignore-deletion-or-insertion-of-certain-regex/45334478#45334478)
There torek explains how `git log` and `git diff` work and how the parameter `-G` works.